# Вызов методa объекта.

Tags: ооп, php

```
class Foo {

    public function bar($x) {
        echo $x;
    }

}

function xyz($cb) {
    $value = rand(1,100);
    call_user_func($cb, $value);
}

$foo = new Foo;
xyz( array($foo, 'bar') );
```

Почему вызывается метод bar?
Я бЫ понял если было примерно написано так
call_user_func($foo->bar, $value);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Смотрим [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php)
   Видим, что первый параметр - это callable.
2. Смотрим что такое ["callable"](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.callable.php).

Или внутренности реализации интересуют? Тогда лучше в исходниках смотреть.

Comment: Спасибо уже разобрался.Не знал толком возможности call_user_func

Answer (score 3):

Потому что такая функция `call_user_func`, прочитайте про аргументы её.